# Conditional Yup Validation is not working

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have `formik form` with below `initialValues`

```
 const initialValues1 = { 
   people: [
   {
     id: Math.random(),
     email: "",
     isNewUser: true,
     profile: {
       firstName: "",
       lastName: "",

     }
   }
  ]
 };
```

I want to validate `firstName` and `lastName` only when is `isNewUser is true` by `Yup` I am trying below but it is not working. How can validate conditionally in `Formik Yup`

```
 people: Yup.array().of(
  Yup.object().shape({
    isNewUser: Yup.boolean(),
    profile: Yup.object().shape({
        firstName: Yup
          .string()
          .when('isNewUser', {
            is: true,
            then: Yup.string().required("First name is required")
          }),
     })
   })
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

[formatted code in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ymnq.png)

```
people: Yup.array().of(
Yup.object({
    isNewUser: Yup.boolean(),
    profile: Yup.object().when('isNewUser', {
        is: true,
        then: Yup.object({
            firstName: Yup.string().required('First name is required'),
        })
    })
})
);
```

`isNewUser` is sibling of `profile` attribute, so we can use it in **when** for defining profile schema not it's child(`first_name`) schema directly.

you can also specify else part using `otherwise` key

```
when({ 'attrbute', is: 'func or value', then: 'schema if is true', otherwise: 'schema if is false'})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema) ,

> Adjust the schema based on a **sibling** or **sibling children fields**. You
>   can provide an object literal where the key is is value or a matcher
>   function, then provides the true schema and/or otherwise for the
>   failure condition.

So move the `isNewUser` to reflect as sibling. **Like this:**

```js
const initialValues1 = { 
   people: [
   {
     id: Math.random(),
     email: "",
     //isNewUser: true, // <--------------- remove this
     profile: {
       firstName: "",
       lastName: "",
       isNewUser: true // <---------------- here.
     }
   }
  ]
 };
```

Comment: I had to read the docs there a few times, and they are still tricky to read. But I _think_ what is meant by that is "`.when` adjusts the schema based on a sibling or sibling children fields. You can provide `.when` either a config object or a function that returns the proper schema based on the sibling value. If the config object has the key `is`, that value is `===` compared to the sibling value. Alternatively the config object can be given a matcher function at the key `value`. In either case, the key `then` specifies the schema when the condition matches..."

Comment: So I would say the docs are not recommending you adjust your data, but rather that `when` adjusts the validation schema based on a sibling value. It would be a poor library if it made demands on how your data must be structured, so I think there is a solution that doesn't require data structure changes, but it isn't easy to find so far...